# How to connect a CR2012 coin cell battery with a PCB?

Tags: power-supply, pcb, connector, batteries

Im trying to build a flat, battery powered PCB assembly that fits into a small gap of approx. 2mm. I have found the [CR2012](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2012.pdf) coin cell with a thickness of 1.2mm, which would be a good fit in terms of size and energy.

My problem is that I have no clue how to connect this battery with my electronics PCB. I searched for battery holders all over the web, but all I found was holders for CR2032 (3.2mm thick) batteries that also would work for CR2012 coin cells (e.g. [this](https://www.wentronic.de/en/batteries/installation-and-accessories/battery-clips-and-holders/3136/cr2012-2032-button-cell-holder) one).

What I seek for is either a proposal for a battery holder for CR2012 with approx. <1.5mm thickness or some general ideas how to connect such a battery (reliably) with a PCB electronic circuit without exceeding 2mm thickness constraint. (The PCB can be as thin as 0.5mm).

Comment: Battery holder for CR2016 coin cell is 1.78 mm tall. Will fit . http://www.batteryholders.com/part.php?pn=BK-5067&original=CR2016&override=CR2016 see also https://www.keyelco.com/product.cfm/Surface-Mount/3028/p/404/id/405/c_id/986/product_id/794

Comment: @Ale..chenski No, this one is 2.16mm above PCB for CR2016. But you got close, thanks!

Comment: No. There are plenty of holders. Here is another one: https://www.keyelco.com/product-pdf.cfm?p=799

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible battery holder I was seeking for is [this](https://www.keyelco.com/product-pdf.cfm?p=799) one. It has a thickness of 1.7mm above PCB, which slightly misses my constraint of <1.5mm. (Maybe there are better proposals?)